# Can I use Hadoop in PHP?

Tags: php, hadoop

Can I use Hadoop in PHP? I want to store a large number of PDF files using Hadoop.

Is there any API to interact with Hadoop in PHP? I configure Hadoop on my server and want to know what to do next.

Comment: I expect you can, but why do you want to do this? Maybe some more details would help us help you - the question is rather broad at the moment. In terms of getting information, I'd start with searching for "Hadoop PHP" in a search engine, see what that gets you - it is actually a much faster way to get assistance than asking a question.

Comment: I learn that, the file handling using hadoop is the best choice. Also, we have a bulk of pdfs and this help to perform my site better.

Comment: I need to improve my site performance.

Comment: Hadoop helps to storing and managing vast amounts of data cheaply and efficiently.

Comment: I want to know that, is anyway to connect php and hadoop?

Comment: Yes: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hadoop+store+files+php. A better answer may be obtained if you can write some code, explain what your Hadoop job is (or is not) doing, and asking for assistance on that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

For interacting with HDFS there is a REST API in the [HttpFS component](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html). For initiating processing jobs such as MapReduce there is a REST API in the [Oozie component](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WebServicesAPI.html). You could call either of those from PHP like any other REST API.